# Flatten a custom dataset JS Object

Tags: javascript, dataset, javascript-objects

Given this dataset :

```js
{
  name: "demo",
  trials: 25,
  data: [ 
    {
      query:
        {planner: "RRT", request: "jc", robot: "ur5"},
      metrics:
        {time: [3,4], length: [32, 33]}
    },
    {
      query:
        {planner: "EST", request: "oc"},
      metrics:
        {time: [6, 8, 9], clearance: [0.7, 0.8, 0.9], success: [1, 0, 1]}
    }
  ]
}
```

Without specifying any keys inside the `query` and `metrics` objects, how could I flatten my dataset to achieve this :

```js
[
    {name: "demo", trials: 25, planner: "RRT", robot: "ur5", request: "jc", time: 3, length: 32},
    {name: "demo", trials: 25, planner: "RRT", robot: "ur5", request: "jc", time: 4, length: 33},
    {name: "demo", trials: 25, planner: "EST", request: "oc", time: 6, clearance: 0.7, success: 1},
    {name: "demo", trials: 25, planner: "EST", request: "oc", time: 8, clearance: 0.8, success: 0},
    {name: "demo", trials: 25, planner: "EST", request: "oc", time: 9, clearance: 0.9, success: 1}
]
```

As this will be integrated within Obervable notebooks, a one liner is preferable but not mandatory.

**EDIT**

The `metrics` object will always be an object of the form `{ attribute: number[] }`. The array size, within the same `metrics` object, are always equal.

Comment: There may not be a way to do this without specifying any key names. Is that a strict requirement?

Comment: No it is not a strict requirement. The folowing keys will never change : `data`, `query` and `metrics`.

Comment: Are there any other guarantees about the shape of the input data? For example, will `metrics` always be an object of the form `{ attribute: number[] }`? Because it's still a bit difficult to tell exactly what needs to happen here. If you could provide more restrictions on the data or more examples, that would make it easier to answer. For example, what should the output look like when there are more elements in the metrics arrays or more keys in the query objects?

Comment: I should have been more specifc. I have updated the dataset and what the output should be to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```js
const data = {
    name: 'demo',
    trials: 25,
    data: [
        {
            query: { planner: 'RRT', request: 'jc', robot: 'ur5' },
            metrics: { time: [3, 4], length: [32, 33] },
        },
        {
            query: { planner: 'EST', request: 'oc' },
            metrics: {
                time: [6, 8, 9],
                clearance: [0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
                success: [1, 0, 1],
            },
        },
    ],
};

const transform = (dataSet) => {
    const { data, ...attributes } = dataSet;
    return dataSet.data
        .map((dataChunk) => {
            const metricEntries = Object.entries(dataChunk.metrics);
            return [
                ...Array(Object.values(dataChunk.metrics)[0].length).keys(),
            ].map((index) => {
                return {
                    ...attributes,
                    ...dataChunk.query,
                    ...Object.fromEntries(
                        metricEntries.map((entry) => {
                            return [entry[0], entry[1][index]];
                        }),
                    ),
                };
            });
        })
        .flatMap((x) => {
            return x;
        });
};

console.log(transform(data));
```

If you have any clarifications, please comment.

Comment: Sweet! Is there an easy way to add all first level objects like `name` and `trials` without specifying their names ? Excluding the `data` object of course.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I updated the answer. If you have any questions about that new part, feel free to ask. For reference, the `{a, b} = c` part is called "[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)" and the `...` is called the "[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)." Here you just leave the `data` part unused.